# Use Javascript to make buttons html

Tags: javascript, css, html, button

hi guys i made some buttons which in CSS active gives a clicking effect. i want to use it to send me to an another page i don't want to change it's style.

Basically right now i have some text in my span which is linked to CSS file to look and act like a button when it is clicked.

i tried using

HTML

```
<span class="Home">Home</span>
```

CSS

```
.Dashboard span
{
   width: 130px;
   height:34px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 25px;
   font-size: 43px;
   font-family: Lemon;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice would be to use an anchor tag.

```
<a class="home" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Home</a>
```

Then the CSS selector:

```
a.home {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:active` CSS pseudo-selector to target elements in their 'active' ('clicked on') state.

If you use a browser inspector, you'll be able to see which styles the browser is applying when the button is being clicked. Note them, and override them. For example:

```
.Dashboard span:active {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

will disable the 'blue box' that appears around active and focussed elements.

If you'd like to read more, take a look at http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to redirect using Javascript, you just have to grab the button and make it so that it will execute:

```
window.location = "http://destination.com";
```

However something to keep in mind is that CSS is very flexible and you can simply apply that styling to an anchor tag so you don't have to go about this roundabout way of getting this same functionality. In fact, I think this is the preferred way to do it.